# Lauterbach debugger with Trace32-Using System.Up command does not work

Tags: debugging, embedded

I am using Lauterbach debugger with Trace32 to debug code flashed on TC1797.
I was able to debug the code I had flashed on the ECU.
But somehow after some time I was not able to put any breakpoints in the code.The software seems to be running and functioning properly.I trid to reflash but the system.Up command also does not seem to work.It gives a message saying "PLL Lock wait".
So the problem is I am no longer able to use the ECU for debugging /reflashing the software.
Can anyone suggest how could I make the ECU recover from the PLL Lock wait condition?What could be the reason of this?

I suspect this happened when I had another calibration tool connected to the ECU while the debugger was connected.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the proble with system clock setting.

Please go throgh your TC1797 user's manual or other relevant documents for how to lock PLL for your required clock settings, which registers values of MCU should be initiallized first?

I believe that will sort you out. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks..but I recently happened to stumble upon this site :http://www.lauterbach.com/frames.html?ephone.html: 
 It talks about similar prob: 
"The information that the PLL is not locked is read by the debugger from the register PMSCR located in the SCU. Whether the PLL is locked or not does not affect the debug connection, so this is not an error but an information.

However this CPU state is often observed in cases where the debugger seems to have a debug connection established but the target does not respond to debugger commands such as break. Although the debug connection is broken completely, the debugger thinks to get valid responses from the target withput being able to recognize that they are invalid. So for the debugger the target state is that the TriCore is running and the PLL is not locked.

An additional check that the debug connection is not working correctly is performing a JTAG chain scan. For this, execute
"Menu -> Help -> Support -> Systeminfo..." and check the results at the end of the file in section "JTAG Chain": If the chain scan failed and you see a message such as "TDO stays constantly low" there is no target connection possible with this device.

There may be two main reasons: Either there is a physical or logical connection problem, or your TriCore device is broken. You may want to cross-check with another target system or debugger. Remove all extension cords and connect the debug cable directly to your target device"

I tried this and it did give me the result: 'TDO constantly low'.Now this has happened with 3 of my ECU's (which happened to work perfectly fine with the debugger connected..so i guess the register values for MCU would have been initialized properly).It would be helpful if someone could suggest if I can recover the ECU's somehow?Is it possible that it's just the debug interface that has gone bad?